# Retrieve data from edit in Kendo scheduler

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, resources, edit, scheduler

I have a Kendo scheduler with editing enabled. It contains "Attendees" as one of the resources. When an edit is made, I want to send an email notification out to all the antendees, informing them of the update. How can I retrieve the list of attendees in a Javascript event that is triggered on edit?

I'm having a lot of trouble finding anything that fits my situation, and being relatively new to this whole environment I'm kind of shooting in the dark.

Here's something I tried that didn't work:

```
var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
var attendees = scheduler.resources[0].dataSource.get(0);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If there is anything you've tried so far, it's best to post it as well. This will give others something to edit so they can help you overcome any hurdle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by using the controller instead of Javascript. It was easy to grab the list of attendees from the view model input of my Update function, and then send email confirmations from there.